# Laravel Mailer not sending or redirecting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

So I have created a contact mailer but it's not sending and therefore not redirecting either, any help would be appreciated.

Here are the relevant files:

Here is the `contact.show`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <section class="title">Contact</section>

  <section class="text-center">
    <p>Do you have a project in mind, or just want a chat to see what I can do for your company?</p>
    <p>Not to worry, just send me an email and I shall be sure to get back to you.</p>
  </section>

  <form method="POST" action="{{ url('contact') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <section class="{{ $errors->has('mame') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <input id="name" type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Full Name">

      @if ($errors->has('name'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
        </span>
      @endif
    </section>

    <section class="{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email Address">

      @if ($errors->has('email'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
        </span>
      @endif
    </section>

    <section class="{{ $errors->has('subject') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" required placeholder="Subject">

      @if ($errors->has('subject'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('subject') }}</strong>
        </span>
      @endif
    </section>

    <section class="{{ $errors->has('message') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <textarea id="message" type="text" name="message" value="message" required placeholder="Type in your message here"></textarea>

      @if ($errors->has('message'))
        <span class="help-block">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('message') }}</strong>
        </span>
      @endif
    </section>

    <button type="submit" class="light-button">Send Equiry</button>
  </form>
@endsection
```

Here is the `ContactController`

```
<?php

namespace benbagley\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    // Render Contact View
    public function show() {
      return view('contact.show');
    }

    public function thank_you(Request $request) {
      $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'subject' => 'required|min:3',
        'HAMessage' => 'required|min:10'
      ]);

      $data = array(
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'message' => $request->message
      );

      Mail::send('contact.mail', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from($data['email']);
        $message->to('ben@benbagley.co.uk');
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
      });

      return redirect('contact.thank_you');
    }
}
```

Here is the `thank you` page

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <section class="thankyou text-center">
    <h3>Thank you for your email</h3>
    <p>I shall reply to you as soon as possible available!</p>
  </section>
@endsection
```

Here are the routes:

```
Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@show');
Route::post('contact', 'ContactController@thank_you');

Route::get('/contact/thank_you', function () {
    return view('contact.thank_you');
});
```

I have also configured MailTrap in the `.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=...
MAIL_PASSWORD=...
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I can't see anything in the logs, any help would be great.

--

**EDIT**

Issue fixed.

```
'HAMessage' => 'required|min:10'
```

should of been

```
'message' => 'required|min:10'
```

and in the array

```
'message' => $request->message
```

should of been

```
'HAMessage' => $request->message
```

**Thank you all for the replies, much appreciated**

Comment: Do you have any log into your mailtrap dashboard ?

Comment: What happens when you submit the form? Open up your chrome dev tools and look in the network tab to see what's happening with your request.

Comment: In your gif, I think the validation rule: `'email' => 'required|email',` is failing as you haven't entered a valid email address. I'm trying to figure out now why the error messages are not showing up in your html. Consider resubmitting the request with dev tools and the network tab open to see what's happening.

Comment: Actually, upon rewatching your gif, I could be wrong about the email rule failing, anyhow, your page is redirecting back for some reason and if you can debug what's going on with each request via dev tools you will definitely get more help.

Comment: Also consider installing laravel-debugbar package, it will help you a great with debugging! https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar#installation

Comment: This is the issue: `'HAMessage' => 'required|min:10'` see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this rule is failing:

```
'HAMessage' => 'required|min:10'
```

And your markup shows `name="message"` as the name attribute:

```
<textarea id="message" type="text" name="message" ...
```

modify the rule from `'HAMessage'` to `'message'` and it should go through okay.

The reason the error wasn't showing up was also because it was being sent back as `'HAMessage'` and you aren't checking for that error.

Consider rethinking your approach to debugging such issues and I'm sure perhaps next time you may work it out yourself straight away next time. Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah I had the variable in the wrong place, oops!

I was using

```
'message' => $request->message
```

when it should be

```
'HAMessage' => $request->message
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if this solved the issue for you and be sure to check out how to use the network tab in chrome dev tools or firefox. It will really help with debugging such issues. All the best with your website!

Comment: FYI, you can use single back ticks to highlight code inline for comments and answers. Markdown doesn't work here lol!

Answer (score 1):

you can redirect in laravel like this

```
   return Redirect::to('contact.thank_you');
```

if you want to pass some parameters then try this

```
return Redirect::to('contact.thank_you')
->with(['parameter_name'=>'Any message']);
```

---

```
if($data){
    Mail::send('contact.view_mail',['email' => $data['email']], function($message)
    use($data){
            $message->to($data['email'])->subject('Welcome!');              
         });
      return Redirect::back()->with('succ_msg',"Email send Successfully");     
                }
```

also check these fields names

```
 $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'subject' => 'required|min:3',
        'HAMessage' => 'required|min:10'
      ]);

      $data = array(
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'HAMessage' => $request->message
      );
```

error in this line `'message' => $request->message`

Comment: Still getting the same issue. Here is a gif of the issue https://gyazo.com/522c35b3deaa25d6366bc7d9ca728622

Answer (score 1):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
```

And make the mail send function like below

```
Mail::send('contact.mail' , $data, function($message) use ($data)
{
    $message->to('ben@benbagley.co.uk',$data['message'])->from($data['email'])->subject($data['subject']);
});
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue. Here is a gif of the issue https://gyazo.com/522c35b3deaa25d6366bc7d9ca728622

Comment: It looks like your validation is failing and you're not showing the errors